# Gerrit JDBC Driver not found

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, gerrit

I have installed gerrit on a Linux Mint machine, and I'm trying to use a mysql database connection for HTTP authentication.
But when I try to start gerrit, I get the following error:

```
ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
com.google.gerrit.common.Die: Cannot connect to SQL database
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.die(AbstractProgram.java:88)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.SiteProgram.createDbInjector(SiteProgram.java:158)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:275)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon.run(Daemon.java:204)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:166)
at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:93)
at com.google.gerrit.launcher.GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:50)
at Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not available
at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.loadDriver(SimpleDataSource.java:171)
at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.<init>(SimpleDataSource.java:85)
at com.google.gerrit.server.schema.DataSourceProvider.open(DataSourceProvider.java:144)
at com.google.gerrit.server.schema.DataSourceProvider.get(DataSourceProvider.java:65)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.SiteLibraryBasedDataSourceProvider.get(SiteLibraryBasedDataSourceProvider.java:52)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.SiteLibraryBasedDataSourceProvider.get(SiteLibraryBasedDataSourceProvider.java:32)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:73)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:63)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
at com.google.gerrit.pgm.util.SiteProgram.createDbInjector(SiteProgram.java:152)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.google.gwtorm.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.loadDriver(SimpleDataSource.java:168)
... 33 more
```

I am copied `mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar` in `/usr/share/java` but still, this error persists.

Can somebody point me to a direction?

Comment: Iirc that belongs into the Gerrit `lib/` folder, doesn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by `lib/` folder? General lib or some other kind of lib folder?

Comment: It might be a bug or something in my current installation but no lib folder has been created for gerrit. I will reinstall if and check again. Thanks

Comment: That's the content of our `/var/gerrit/review/lib` folder: `bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar  bcpkix-jdk15on-149.jar  bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar  bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar  mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar  mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar`.

Comment: StephenKing, please post this as answer, since it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to leave `/usr/share/java` untouched. Anything you put there will be lost when you upgrade the next time. Instead, define your own common location for your drivers. If it is just for you, a subdirectory of your home location might be good: `mkdir ~/jdbc`.

Then copy your .jar for your jdbc driver in that location.

Then depending on how you run your java code, you will have to figure out how to include your jar's into your classpath.

1. standalone java program started with command-line `java`, then use the `-cp` parameter option.
2. Application Servers like Tomcat, or Weblogic, refer their documentation. Note that many suggest a drop location within the app server install, but for the same reasons as for the `/usr/share/java`, I would advise not to do so. Actually tomcat allows you to separate out CATALINA_HOME from CATALINA_BASE to solve that issue.

Either way, it appears that the exception was generated from a simple `main`, not a web app, so I assume you can go for the first option.

Comment: Good point on leaving the `/usr/share/java` untouched. But where/ or how should I install mysql library so `gerrit` is able to connect to the mysql database?